# Solution of Neumann problem for Laplace equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, greens-theorem

I have the following problem:

Let $ u $ be in $ C^2(\Omega) $ and in $ C^1(\overline{\Omega}) $, where $ \Omega $ is a normal bounded domain in $ R^n $, and suppose that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\Delta u&=0 ~~ \text{in}~~\Omega\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}&=0 ~~ \text{in}~~\partial\Omega
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Then show that $ u $ is constant in $ \overline{\Omega} $.

Here I try like this:

From Green's first identity,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega}[u\Delta w+(\nabla u).(\nabla w)]dv=\int_{\partial\Omega}u\dfrac{\partial w}{\partial n}d\sigma
\end{equation*}
taking $ u=1 $ and $ w=u $, I have
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega}\Delta udv=\int_{\partial\Omega}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}d\sigma
\end{equation*}
And using the fact that
$$ \overline{\Omega}=\Omega\cup\partial\Omega$$
And
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\overline{\Omega}}f=\int_{\Omega}f+\int_{\partial\Omega}f-\int_{\Omega\cap\partial\Omega}f
\end{equation*}
I got
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\overline{\Omega}}\Delta udv=\int_{\partial\Omega}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}d\sigma-\int_{\Omega}0.\nabla udv+\int_{\partial\Omega}\Delta udv-\int_{\Omega\cap\partial\Omega}\Delta udv
\end{equation*}
which is reduced to
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\overline{\Omega}}\Delta udv=\int_{\partial\Omega}\Delta udv
\end{equation*}
Now in order to be $ u $ constant on $ \overline{\Omega} $, the integrand $ \Delta u $ must be 0 (?!). To be that the integral on the right hand side should vanish. But how can I show that? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ be a solution to
\begin{align}
\Delta u&=0 \,\,\, \text{in}\,\,\,\Omega, \tag{1a} \\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}&=0 \,\,\,\text{in}\,\,\,\partial\Omega. \tag{1b}
\end{align}
Then
$$
\int_{\Omega}\Delta (u^2)\,dv=\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{\partial u^2}
{\partial n}\,d\sigma=\int_{\partial\Omega}2u\,\frac{\partial u}
{\partial n}\,d\sigma=0. \tag{2}
$$
On the other hand, $\Delta (u^2)=2[u\Delta u+(\nabla u)^2]=2(\nabla u)^2$,
so $(2)$ implies
$$
\int_{\Omega}(\nabla u)^2\,dv=0, \tag{3}
$$
from which follows that $u$ is constant.

Comment: You could also just use that $\int_\Omega \vert \nabla u\vert^2\,dx=-\int_\Omega u \Delta u \, dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} u \frac {\partial u}{\partial n} \, dS =0.$

Comment: But what about on $ \partial\Omega $? to be $ u $ constant on $ \bar{\Omega} $, it should also be on the boundary. $ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0 $ in $ \partial\Omega $ doesn't imply $ u $ is constant, i think. (as $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}=\nabla u.n=0\nRightarrow u\equiv const.$)

Comment: Yes Really, thank you.